# Get stacktrace of function with throws Exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, stack-trace

Lets say I have a function like this

```
public JSONObject parseMessage(InputStream fileName) throws Exception {
```

And it throws an error where can I get the stack trace of that?

I know if I have something like

```
try {} catch(Exception e) {//I could save it to a var here}
```

But how to I save the stacktrace to are variable with a function that `throws Exception`?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: You want to get the stacktrace in a function before you throw an exception from that function?

Comment: You could `catch` it, work on it, and then `throw` it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace(java.lang.Throwable)) to convert an Exception stack trace to String.

This class is available in Apache commons-lang-2.2.jar:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(Throwable)
```

Comment: Or just use the existing `.getStackTrace()` which returns `StackTraceElement[]` which has a perfectly good `.toString()`.

Comment: Or `Arrays.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());`.